# Outer Product Other form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, quantum-computer

The outer product of a ket $|\psi\rangle$ with a bra $\langle\phi|$ according to the textbook *Quantum Computing Explained by D. McMahon*, behaves likes an operator. He illustrates this by applying an arbitrary ket $|\chi\rangle$:

$$ (|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)|\chi\rangle = |\psi\rangle\langle\phi|\chi\rangle = (\langle\phi|\phi|\chi\rangle)|\psi\rangle $$

but I don't understand why is:

$$|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|χ\rangle = (\langle\phi|\phi|χ\rangle)|\psi\rangle $$

**Addendum:**
The book actually states the above equation, see the attached screen shot [image]
Which should read
$$(|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)|\chi\rangle = |\psi\rangle(\langle\phi|\chi\rangle )= (\langle\phi|\chi\rangle)|\psi\rangle $$

Comment: Could you clarify your question? As written, it is a bit unclear what you are asking. The final expression $\langle \phi | \phi | \chi \rangle |\psi \rangle$ does not (necessarily) make sense. That which is "sandwiched" between the bra and the ket should be an operator, but you have $\phi$ for both the ket and the operator. Is this intentional? Do you mean that $|\phi \rangle$ is an eigenket of operator $\phi$, better written as $\hat \phi$ for clarity, with eigenvalue $\phi$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Also the book is not by macmahon, it's mcmahon

Comment: The book seems to be wrong. If somebody approves my edit you'll see. Yili you could have just said, that it actually says so in the book. Books are just wrong sometimes.

Comment: I think it is just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

$\langle \varphi|\chi \rangle$ is a complex number, so $|\psi \rangle (\langle \varphi|\chi \rangle )$ = $(\langle \varphi|\chi \rangle )|\psi \rangle $

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).